# Problems with calculations and conversions in Visual Basic Form

Tags: visual-studio-2008, type-conversion

In the code below I get the "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid." error. Can anyone let me know why this is ? Thanks.

`Public Class Form1
    Dim SalesDecimal As Decimal
    Const BasePay As Decimal = 250D
    Const CommissionRate As Decimal = 0.15D
    Dim Quota As Integer = 1000
    Dim TotalSalesAmt, TotalComAmt, GrandTotal As Decimal`

```
Private Sub PayToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PayToolStripMenuItem.Click
    SalesDecimal = Decimal.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
    TextBox2.Text = Decimal.Parse(CommissionCalc(SalesDecimal))
    ***TextBox4.Text = Decimal.Parse(CommissionRate * SalesDecimal)***
    If TextBox3.Text < 1000 Then
        TextBox4.Text = ""
    End If
    TotalSalesAmt += TextBox3.Text
    TotalComAmt += TextBox4.Text
    GrandTotal += TextBox2.Text
End Sub
Private Function CommissionCalc(ByVal Sales As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim Total = (SalesDecimal * CommissionRate) + BasePay
    If Sales >= Quota Then
        Return Total
    Else

        Return BasePay
    End If
End Function

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ClearToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ClearToolStripMenuItem.Click
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""


End Sub

Private Sub ColorToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ColorToolStripMenuItem.Click
    With ColorDialog1
        ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox2.ForeColor = .Color

    End With
End Sub

Private Sub FontToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FontToolStripMenuItem.Click
    With FontDialog1
        .ShowDialog()
        TextBox2.Font = .font
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub SummaryToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SummaryToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim MessageString As String
    MessageString = "Amount of sales: " & TotalSalesAmt.ToString("C") _
    & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine _
    & "Total Commissions: " & TotalComAmt.ToString("C") _
    & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine _
    & "Total Pay: " & GrandTotal.ToString("C")
    MessageBox.Show(MessageString, "Sales Summary", MessageBoxButtons.OK)


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Put "Option Strict On" at the top of the source code file.  You'll get a hundred errors that will take you a week to fix.  But then you'll have learned the difference between a string and a number.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I saw exactly what my problems were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast your variables when pushing them into the text box.

```
If TextBox3.Text < 1000 Then
    TextBox4.Text = ""
End If
TotalSalesAmt += TextBox3.Text
TotalComAmt += TextBox4.Text
GrandTotal += TextBox2.Text
```

For instance your TextBox3.Text above is a String, not a Decimal. Your trying to move through types without casting them to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

> TextBox2.Text = Decimal.Parse(CommissionCalc(SalesDecimal))

You are using Decimal.Parse incorrectly. Decimal.Parse is used to parse a String to a Decimal type, you seem to be using it to do both a string to decimal and decimal to string. If you want to get the string representation of the decimal value you should use ToString. In the example above form your code, CommisionCalc returns a Decimal number, you need to call CommissionCalc(SalesDecimal).ToString() not Decimal.Parse()